# Create a custom Full sized Calendar Control

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, custom-controls

How can I make a custom control that show the calendar control in a much larger view. Like [this](http://i46.tinypic.com/91jayg.jpg) or like the calendar view in outlook 2007. Do I have to make a custom class or can I just attempt to resize the calendar. I am doing this in WPF so I use WPF Toolkit

Comment: No, It's really not that ambiguous, vague or incomplete. He's asking how to make the WPF calendar bigger. Maybe your brain is not quite large enough to grasp the question. Next time, be a little nicer when you close someones question you Jerk!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a custom class -- the control in WPF is designed to be a picker, not a displayer of data on a timeline. That stated, you could try extending, and retemplating the calandar control to allow display of data in the form you want.

if you are just looking for a huge, lickable date picker, then you could just use a [scale factor transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) to make it bigger, and more lickable.

Comment: the larger the more lickable?